# Why can't I set breakpoints in certain files in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There's certain files that I can never seem to set a breakpoint in react-native. I have a set of "utils" files that are used across the web and iOS version of my app:

```
\utils.js
\utils.ios.js
\utils.common.js
```

At the top of both **utils.js** and **utils.common.js** I'm exporting **utils.common.js** like this

```
export * from './utils.common';
```

In other files I import utils like this:

```
import { someFunc } from './utils';
```

utils.js is loaded by the web app and utils.ios.js is loaded on iOS.

Now I want to say that everything works just fine and I can set breakpoints in other js files in my project. The functions and variables from utils.common.js are exported without any issues, but I CANNOT set a breakpoint in utils.common.js on anything other than declaration lines, which is extremely frustrating when I need to debug.

```
function a(b) {    // I can set a breakpoint here
  let b = b * 2;   // I can't set a breakpoint here
  return b;        // or here :s
}
```

Does anyone have insight as to why this might be happening?

Is there an npm package I can add or a babel setting that will make debugging more consistent in react-native?

Comment: Very frustrating.